# Java JSF h:outPutText - no tag was defined

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying to implement example from Java EE book, where JSF 2.0 was used. I'm using JSF 2.2 and this is example straight from the book:

xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

```
<h:outPutText value="#{notowanie.dzien}" >
                            <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="short" type="date" />
                            </h:outputText>
```

It doesn't work like this:

HTTP Status 500 - Error Parsing /historia.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 25] The element type "h:outPutText" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

So I changed it to:

```
<h:outPutText value="#{notowanie.dzien}" />
                            <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="short" type="date" />
```

HTTP Status 500 - /historia.xhtml @23,49  Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: outPutText

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

Tried h:outputText ? With no camelcase?

http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputText.html

Comment: Oh, yes - that was the problem ! I don't know, why I didn't see it before. Thank you :)

Comment: Generally output is one word, so it doesn't need to be written in camelcase:) But good luck with your project:) If that's all you can close this task:)